# How to extract a cell value from a given .xlsx sheet in a workbook using "xlsx" package from node?

Tags: node.js, sheetjs

I want to extract a cell value from a given .xlsx file from a particular row and column in a given sheet from a workbook using a npm module ".xlsx". Please suggest me any way to extract the value so that I can use the test data from the sheet.

Given I was able to go to a particular sheet

```
const xlsx =require("xlsx"); 
const wb=xlsx.readFile("test_data.xlsx"); 
const ws=wb.Sheets["Sheet1"]
```

Comment: What did you try so far ?

Comment: Please add it to the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use this. You can install const `xlsx-populate`

Then this the function

```
 XlsxPopulate.fromFileAsync("./Book1.xlsx")
        .then(workbook => {

            // choose the sheet and a cell.
            const value = workbook.sheet("Sheet1").cell("A1").value();

            console.log(value);
        });
```

Comment: If you need get all cell values you can use `workbook.sheet("Sheet1").usedRange().value();`

Answer (score 1):

You could load the workbook into memory, retrieve the sheet & then log out the cells in order to debug that you are looking at the correct information:

```js
const workbook = xlsx.readFile('file path')
let worksheet = workbook.Sheets['Sheet name'];
let cell = worksheet['C3'].v; // Column C, Row 3 (assuming there's data there)

console.log('Cell data', cell)
```

If it all checks out you can use this information in loops, maps or any other means to render.

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.